# How can I get the same protection shopping with a credit card, without using a credit card?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, debit-card, security

Following [the advice of Dave Ramsey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Ramsey#Teachings), I'm getting rid of my credit cards. The problem is, the alternatives don't seem safe. There are people who stand around the cash machines watching people take out large sums of cash. And there are merchants who have personal scanners who steal card details. It seems safer to use a credit card, because at least my actual bank balance can't be immediately drained.

Is there another way to make card payments that lacks the risk of being without my money if I paid with debit card, but also stops me from running up debt and interest?

Comment: Who is Dave Ramsey and what was the advice?

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to stop using credit cards? That is more important than who advised that. Also don't listen to Dave Ramsey.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by following said advice? Do you even know? It's not a good idea to follow advice without knowing what it is supposed to accomplish and how it is supposed to accomplish it.

Comment: @littleadv Dave Ramsey's advice as relates to this question is "use cash for everything."

Comment: @Teepeemm that's a ridiculous advice

Comment: So one advantage with cash (I don't know Dave Ramsey's reasoning), that doesn't seem to be addressed in the answers, is that it forces you to be at least peripherally aware of how much you're spending throughout the week/month/...  E.g., if I take out $300 from the ATM every Sunday, I see how much money I have left that week every time I take out my wallet.  (I'm sure there are apps now for things like this, but I don't know how good they are.)

Comment: @Kimball I know how much I am spending even if not using cash. Even if I did not it is not difficult to use a spreadsheet or one of the many tools to track your spending and they are easier to use if you don't use cash. Some banks even provide apps to do that which mean you don't have to enter your payments. It depends on what your mental view is.

Comment: @mmmmmm I just check up credit card online a few times a month.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes - my bank also SMSs me weekly the total spent so I can quickly see any wrong charges.

Comment: @Kimball cash is “spent” as soon as it hits my wallet.  Credit (or debit) card and ACH are *the* ways to track spending.

Comment: Ramsey's suggestions aren't necessarily the best, when taken objectively and with consideration for everything involved, because his suggestions often tap into psychology, all centered around debt elimination. Ramsey's suggestion that you don't use cards at all is largely based on the assumption you don't have the personal responsibility to keep your credit spending within your budget. If that's not true for you, then keep your cards.

Comment: @mmmmmm and other commenters: While you may be, my point is I think most people are not, and the level of effort required may depend on your bank etc.  Also, seeing how much you are physically spending while you make each purchase is psychologically different than just seeing it periodically online. I am not promoting one approach versus another. I use cards in the US and cash in Japan, and see advantages of both.

Comment: @Kimball "Seeing how much you are physically spending" However, that doesn't seem to be the OP's goal. OP isn't opposed to cards nor does OP want to use cash. OP just wants the "credit" part of a credit card because it provides a security buffer between the bank account, but not the "interest" part.

Comment: IIRC, Dave Ramsey's advice isn't just to use cash for everything, it's to take out as much cash at the beginning of a month as you think you'll need, then put it in envelopes according to how much you're budgeting for different categories, and then whenever you buy something, use the appropriate envelope. Also, be a Christian. He's a weird mix of self-appointed financial guru and evangelical Christian. His advice may help some people with self-control issues, but it's a lot of hassle with questionable benefit for people in general.

Comment: @Acccumulation that's even worse. Budgeting through physical cash end envelopes? What century is that???

Comment: @mmmmmm If you don't think it is hard to set up a spreadsheet and enter all expenditures and keep it up to date, you are not a typical person, and your advice on the subject of personal finance and money should not reflect your own personal experience.  I find doing mortgage calculations using generating polynomials both easy and informative, but I don't give people advice based on the assumption a random person can.

Comment: *there are merchants who have personal scanners who steal card details* — I thought that was only true for swipe cards.  Do those still exist?  I thought that stealing the details from a chip card was very difficult and had only be done in a lab setting?

Comment: @gerrit - I think some countries have very backward payments systems e.g. USA

Comment: @Yakk - OK spreadsheets might be to complex for many - but many apps do make this easy and several use the envelope budgeting system. As to giving advice I would start with what I suggest and then if someone is having trouble with that ask them more detailed questions. Ramsey I suspect starts by assuming either you are already having debt issues or that you are innumerate - I would start by assuming a reasonable level of numeracy

Comment: Advice like this sounds like what you'll typically hear in the productivity/motivation/finance/etc space: it contains some truth and may be useful for some people, but it ignores nuance and the fact that not everyone is the same, the advice givers often don't explain the reasoning behind the advice (so you can figure out whether, when and how to follow it) and they often exaggerate the possible benefits (*you'll be a millionaire if you stop drinking daily Starbucks*). Dave Ramsey and others are selling their personality and image, rather than actual good advice.

Comment: @mmmmmm The [tag:envelope-system] is not only for innumerate people, is it?  I use it with gnucash and although it is a bit cumbersome, I find it still easier to use than a formal budget.

Comment: @gerrit No I have used a envelope system myself - it is easier to explain which is why I mentioned it but if you do undertstand more then you can use more flexible things than just the simple version.

Answer (score 45):

### Dave Ramsey is well-meaning, but wrong sometimes.

*Aren't we all*.

What Dave is *really* saying is "You can't have credit cards because I don't trust you to use them responsibly".

I realize that sounds psychotic as a blanket statement to all humans, but Dave Ramsey understands that the people who listen to Dave Ramsey are a particular class to whom Dave is marketed: Average Regular Folk *who are not that great at money*, and realistically probably never will become all that great at money.  The message makes sense in that context.

### The question is: can you be trusted?

If you can use the credit card responsibly, go ahead and have one.

You simply need to follow the Suze Orman rules for credit cards: think before you charge and pay them off in full every month (which eliminates interest).

And by the way, you may already have one: cutting the card is a symbolic act, it doesn't close the account. They'll cheerfully send you another one. They'll also be happy to adjust credit limits if you find that helpful, talk to a human at customer service. (though adjusting *upward* will require a credit check).

Another option is a **secured** credit card. This is a normal credit card, however the bank requires you to make a cash deposit equal to your credit limit.  If you feel you need the help of a bank to keep you honest, then you can select one of those.  Or you can "cook your own" by choosing a credit card from a bank, and opening a savings account with that bank and willingly depositing the amount equal to the credit limit, and then just don't take the money out.

Comment: First I had to look up Dave Ramsey, now I have to look up Suze Orman. My arrangement with my bank is that my credit limit is my bank balance. I exchange my card for a new one fairly regularly, because I buy things online, and some of these vendors retain your credit information and don't ask for permission. This is for your "convenience."

Comment: The callers / emailers in financial crisis who get through the screening process by Dave Ramsey's call-in show producers are hand-picked examples of walking talking financial disasters who can best benefit by Dave Ramsey's standard advice. They've already proven that they lack financial discipline, so for them the first step to recovery is to cut up their credit cards.

Comment: @wastrel check out PCI-DSS. Visa and Mastercard dictate very severe limits on what merchants are allowed to retain re: your credit card info and punish merchants brutally for data breaches.  They shouldn't be saving your CVV#, they should be establishing a contractual relationship with their bank that allows followup charges on cards which have already been used. This "right of followup charges without CVV" is granted for merchants who reasonably need it. Netflix yes, McDonalds no.  Report it... drop a PCI-DSS audit on their head. (much worse than an IRS audit.)

Comment: There are also banks that offer credit cards that can be blocked for particular MCCs.

Comment: @Wastrel Besides what  Harper - Reinstate Monica said, if you don't trust merchants, you can virtual credit cards/tokenize your PAN so you can keep the same base credit card without merchants being able to retain useful information.

Comment: "Dave Ramsey understands that the people who listen to Dave Ramsey are a particular class to whom Dave is marketed" IOW, listening to Dave Ramsey for CC advice is a bit like going to an AA meeting for wine-buying advice: if you're an alcoholic, much of the AA advice will be useful, but otherwise probably not so much.

Comment: Also need to be 100% certain the card you use daily has a grace period. A quick search shows they are not *required* to have a grace period, but if they do it must be at least 21 days. I haven't heard of a card in many years without a grace period, but there may still be some out there. But if you have anything close to decent credit you should be able to get a card with a grace period and no annual fee.

Comment: yes @wastrel I should have been clearer. Per PCI-DSS they are not **allowed** to store certain data - I don't recall but definitely not your CVV, possibly not your expiry.  They can't even store it for a second, that's why if a purchase page ever rejects, you have to re-enter it.  *Then, if they are the kind of business that does follow-on charges e.g. Netflix, their bank allows them to do it without CVV etc.*  So if they get hacked, it is not in their systems. PCI-DSS basically assumes they'll get hacked.

Comment: Is Suze Orman well known in the US? She did a fair amount of work with FNB here in SA and was well liked.

Comment: @Acccumulation "like going to an AA meeting for wine-buying advice" Roughly, yes, in that the AA will tell you "don't even go near that."

Comment: i don't think the question is 'can you be trusted,' it's that data shows that nearly everyone spends more money when they use cc vs cash.  it may be a small amount of increase  for people who are good with money but the percentage of people whose habits don't change *at all* is extremely small

Comment: @NeilMeyer Yes, Suze is from the USA. Lived in Berkeley CA.  Worked at the Buttercup Cafe. I've eaten there.

Comment: None of these provide pre-emptive budgeting with passive enforcement, which is at least half of the point of "cash only" systems I find.  Ie, "if you withdraw 300$ per week and run out", there is an enforcement mechanism (you have to go to the bank to break the rules), while doing so with a credit card is much more difficult.  Even secured credit cards are poor at this; they don't let you know constantly how much you have left by the number of bills left in your wallet, and they often penalize you financially if you go over the limit instead of just refusing to provide you with more funds.

Comment: @eps of course people spend more with cc than cash.  If you're only doing cash transactions then it's impossible to spend more cash than the cash you have.

Comment: @MTA I don't know if the show has changed since then but I've watched a couple of episodes and while most do lack discipline some callers don't fit that, like some have accumulated money due to not spending and are now asking what to do with it or some callers don't even fit the show and reject Ramsey's ideas. But that makes it more weird that his suggestions are still so unflexible to fit other people

Answer (score 14):

In the United Sates the safest method of paying is with a credit card. There is always a lag of weeks between the usage and the pulling money from the bank account. There are ways to dispute transactions.

Checking the items on the bill before transferring funds to pay the bill will eliminate all penalties if somebody does get a fraudulent transaction into the system.

You will also find that some transactions can't easily be done with a debit card: renting a car. Others may require extra large hold for contingencies: a hotel room.

Answer (score 13):

If you are able to do so, continue to use your credit card, but monitor your use and keep it under control.

I always keep a certain amount on a separate account which is supposed to be seen together with my credit card and which ensures I am never "really" in debt. This includes always paying my card off in full.

Answer (score 5):

In the US (I can't vouch for elsewhere) debit cards are under different regulations than credit cards and are not as safe, but can be used in most places credit cards can be. You do have to maintain a high enough balance in the account behind the debit card to cover all anticipated purchases/holds/whatever.

Personally, I'm perfectly happy continuing to use credit cards and making darned sure I pay them off in full every month, so I never pay interest  But if you can't resist the temptation to let payments slide, there are definitely arguments for not having one.

EDIT: Other folks have mentioned one-time credit card numbers, and prepaid cards. I'd add that some banks will let you turn a card on and off via their website or phone app, and a few may now offer the option of doing two-factor authentication on a card. All of these add some security, and may remind you to consider your budget before buying; the prepaid in particular is like taking out a cash withdrawal in that you can find only spend what you've loaded it with.

Comment: Valid point. Rephrased.

Comment: "You do have to maintain a high enough balance in the account" - sadly not the case if the account permits overdrafts.
Even if your account does NOT permit overdrafts, you can (as I discovered) overdraw it with a debit card. You try to charge the card to pay for lunch, they decline it and apply a declined-payment fee, which overdraws the account, then they apply an unauthorized overdraft fee, which overdraws it further; and if I remember right there was a yet third fee on top of that. By the time they were done, I was close to a hundred bucks in debt for a sandwich I didn't even get to buy!

Comment: @DewiMorgan That depends on your individual bank's policies and what you have agreed to. I'm not attempting to cover every possible permutation here, and in fact if one follows my assertion that you have to have a balance high enough to cover charges one should not get into the overdraft situation under any but exceptional circumstances.

Comment: @DewiMorgan As keshlam said, depends on the bank. One that I deal with recently has a very clearly phrased option as to whether allow overdrafts via debit card - say "No" and that's it - the transaction will be rejected if you don't have the funds and end of story. They're also pretty good about other fees (or lack thereof). Not going to recommend a specific bank (gets out of date, and banks merge, etc.) but general advice is ask around in your area and generally look for a small local bank - no guarantee but that often helps (until 4 or 5 mergers later when they're in the top 3).

Comment: Credit unions are also worth looking at, being more member-focused than banks. And with the Branch Exchange program they can have coverage that rivals some much larger banks.

Comment: Also, even if the problem is eventually resolved, it is a LOT more stressful in the meantime for your bank account to be missing a thousand bucks than it is for the cc company to claim you owe them a thousand more dollars.

Comment: EU has three different regulations IIRC: debit cards, credit cards directly issued (AmEx), and credit cards issued via banks (Visa/MasterCard).

Comment: @DewiMorgan Since 2010, by law, you must [opt in to debit card overdrafts](https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/pressreleases/bcreg20091112a.htm). Anybody who doesn't opt in may not be charged overdraft fees. Before that, yes, what you described was a very common occurrence.

Comment: @user71659 Great to hear! :) And yes, this was around 2009.

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar position at one point, wanting to do what I could to ensure I didn't rack up a bunch of debt.  In the U.S. at least, credit cards have protections (and rewards) that other payment types don't, so it's difficult to get the same amount of protection with some other instrument.  I did a lot of research and came up with a slightly different solution.  Instead of trying to make a debit card (or similar) behave like a credit card, I took a credit card and made it behave like a debit card.

I got rid of my existing credit cards and took out a new card through my primary bank, specifically requesting a relatively low limit (I think I started at $250).  Since I got the card through my bank, I could manage it via online banking just like it was any other bank account, viewing balances, transferring funds instantly, etc.  Every day, I would check the account and pay off whatever balance was outstanding.  If I couldn't pay off that day's balance, I couldn't use the card again until I did.  That effectively turned it into a debit card, since any money spent came out of my account almost immediately.  As time went on and my financial discipline improved, I could go from checking and paying off the account daily to every other day, then weekly, and eventually to only checking it once per month.  After going a year or so of monthly payoffs without carrying any debt forward, I knew I had built enough discipline to handle a normal credit card.

Pros of this technique:

- The card is inherently a credit card, so you get all of a credit card's protections and rewards.
- Unlike a debit card, this method contributes to a positive credit history.
- Easy to manage using the same tools you already use to manage your bank accounts.
- The credit limit is a hard stop that prevents you from overspending and limits the worst-case debt that you can accumulate.
- A low credit limit means you can't make large purchases with the card.  The extra hassle of writing a check or withdrawing cash will remind you to really think about whether that purchase is necessary.
- In an emergency, carrying a balance on your credit card for 4-5 days is usually a lot cheaper than overdrawing your debit account and relying on your bank's overdraft protection.
- Banks will sometimes give you better interest rates on credit cards if you also have checking/savings accounts with them that typically have balances at or above the credit limit (less risk for them).  If all goes well, the interest rate won't even matter because you won't be carrying any debt long enough to accrue interest.

Cons:

- Credit limit is very low, at least at first.  This isn't too severe of a problem if you're paying off the balance daily.  Once you graduate to less frequent payoffs, you might want to bump the balance up a little.  You probably won't ever be able to pay large expenses (like rent) using this card.
- Requires a degree of discipline to be successful.  Building financial discipline is the most important part of this entire exercise, though, so I don't recommend any method that provides technical constraints to avoid debt without requiring any discipline on the part of the user.
- Some credit card rewards (like airline miles) are given based on the balance listed on the monthly statement.  Paying off balances before the statement can mean those amounts aren't included in the rewards calculations.  On the cards I've seen at least, those that give a flat X% cash back on each purchase were more likely to accrue full rewards regardless of whether the balance was paid early.
- Significantly more difficult if the card isn't from your primary bank.  You want to be able to instantly transfer funds from your checking account to pay off the card balance.  If the card is from another institution, there's a delay of several days before the payoff shows up and the whole thing gets harder to manage.

I found this technique to be like a bicycle with training wheels.  It provided everything I needed to learn how to use a credit card safely and responsibly while preventing me from doing anything too stupid.  Poor financial discipline still incurred penalties, but even in the worst case it wasn't something that I couldn't dig myself out of within a couple of months.

Answer (score 2):

**PREPAID CREDIT CARD**

If your goal is just to protect your bank account by minimizing how frequently you directly access it while also avoiding building up debt and interest on a credit card, you can buy yourself a prepaid credit card.

You can only spend the amount of money you put onto the prepaid credit card and because of that you can't spend money you don't have. It protects your bank account because it has no link to your bank account and you can't go into debt on it like a normal credit card.

Don't lose the card though because the card is worth whatever you put onto it and there's no other way to access that money.

EDIT: Actually, it seems that if your prepaid credit card is stolen it is possible to lock it down and get it re-issued. That means the credit card is not the sole access point to those funds.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Ramsey would tell you that debit cards from MasterCard and Visa offer the same $0 fraud liability protection that credit cards do.

From [his website](https://www.ramseysolutions.com/banking/5-reasons-why-debit-is-better-than-credit):

> What most people don’t realize is that credit companies like Visa or Mastercard protect their debit card purchases too. If you run your debit card as credit when you make a purchase (which may show up as “pending” on your account), you have the exact same protections as a credit card.

He's not wrong in saying this.  When you use a MasterCard or Visa (as well as other card brands), you have $0 fraud liability, whether that card is a credit card or a debit card.  If a fraudulent transaction comes through, you dispute the transaction, and the bank will give you your money back.  A thief using your card in this way has ultimately stolen from the bank, not from you.

However, there is a difference between how credit cards and debit cards work.  When a charge is made on a credit card, the amount is borrowed/applied to your credit limit.  If a fraudulent charge comes through, it is not a big deal: you dispute the charge, the bank investigates and removes it, and you never have to pay it.

With a debit card, though, charges are removed from your checking account immediately.  As a result, a large fraudulent charge can potentially empty your bank account before you realize what has happened, which can result in further problems when you make legitimate purchases.  In the end, the charge will be removed (the charge can still be disputed and the bank will give you the money back), but in the mean time if your bank account is empty you will have legitimate bills that need to be paid, possibly incurring overdraft fees or late penalties.

If you want to get rid of credit cards and only use debit cards, there are ways to mitigate the risk.  If you keep a fairly large balance in your checking account (you can do this by keeping some or all of your emergency fund in your checking account), then a fraudulent charge is less likely to remove most or all of your balance.  Another way to handle the risk is to purchase identity theft insurance (which Dave Ramsey recommends) that can work with the bank to solve the problem and pay for any losses you incur as a result.

Personally, I would describe myself a a fan of Dave Ramsey and have benefited from much of his teaching.  However, I do use credit cards on a regular basis, because I see debit cards as too much of a risk for me.  I use the credit cards as if they were debit cards: I only purchase things using my credit card that I already have the money for, and when a purchase is made I account for that purchase right away in my budgeting software even before the credit card bill is ultimately due, ensuring that I have the money to pay it in full each month.  However, for some people that I know, the temptation for using a credit card irresponsibly is too much, and they are better off not having a credit card.

Comment: Fraudulent charges that clear out your bank account before you realize what's happened can have long-lasting repercussions.  A coworker of mine learned this the hard way.  The bank reversed the fraudulent transactions about 90 days later.  In the mean time, he had to figure out ways to pay his living expenses.  Reversing the charges did not wipe out the overdraft charges nor the late payment fee on his mortgage payment nor those on utilities he had set to pay automatically.  It also lowered his credit score and got him on a list of "bad check writers" for seven years.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Agreed, +1. That’s why I don’t use debit cards.

Comment: Miller: You wrote "In the end, it will likely get all worked out...." which doesn't seem consistent with the rest of your excellent post.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy You are right.  I have reworded the end of that paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get something called a [Charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_card) [Card](https://wallethub.com/credit-cards/charge-cards/) which works like a Credit Card (with all the consumer protections of one, including being able to charge-back a merchant and usually winning the dispute, the peace of mind that if lost you can easily cancel it with a phone call, etc.) without the line of credit that is typically attached to a credit card. Since banks are no longer making money off the card's APR, these cards typically have a non-zero annual fee to cover the perks they give, but if you choose a card smartly to make use of the perks, you can earn back the value of this annual fee.

A charge card must be paid off at the end of every month in full (some have even more frequent deadlines, weekly or even every few days). It will overdraw your bank account if you don't have enough funds to pay it off. You may still be tempted to use it to pay for something you don't have money for, but the ramifications of doing so are significantly more serious than just high interest.